# While retriving ArrayList from Map giving null pointer exception

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

```
CDBMap1=cdbMapping.GetListData();

ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();

for (int len=0; len<Subheaders.size(); len++) {
    System.out.println("len value "+len);
    String RequiredValue=requiredFields[len];

    data=CDBMap1.get(RequiredValue);
    FirstHeader.add(len,data.get(1));
    SecondHeader.add(len,data.get(2));
    ThirdHeader.add(len,data.get(3));
    FifthHeader.add(len,data.get(4));
    SixthHeader.add(len,data.get(5));
    SeventhHeader.add(len,data.get(6));
    EighthHeader.add(len,data.get(7));

    data.clear();
}
```

I am trying to access the array list from map named CDBMap1. this map contain near about 220 key value pairs but while accessing 41th entry it is giving me null pointer exception. i checked the 41th entry in map it is fine.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger to hopefully get the exact line where the `NullPointerException` is happening?

Comment: yaa null pointer exception is there when value of len varible in for loop is 41

Comment: OK but can you give us a line number?  Maybe then we might be able to get some insight here.

Comment: at FirstHeader.add(len,data.get(1)); line it is giving me null pointer exception because size of arraylist named data is coming null

Comment: the null pointer exception is at line no 10